# RewriteCond + RewriteRule redirect with strings and multiple "sub-domains"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website running on nginx and my index file is inside a folder. /folder/index.php

I asked my website host to add a "index" directive but they said it is not possible (insecure) and told me to do that by RewriteRule.

So every time that someone type my web address, he need to goes to /folder/file.php

But is not that simple, because I also need that when someone clicks on my banners, I receive the strings from Google URL Builder.

And there is more: my website allows the user to make its own URL, like mydomain.com/user so I already have this RewriteRule:

```
^/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)$  /myhotsite.php?ID=$1
flag: Continue (last)
```

The myhotsite.php handles the query and mount the webpage based on a MySQL consult.

So let me try to explain in topics:

1. mydomain.com -> /folder/file.php
2. mydomain.com/?utm_source=blablabla -> /folder/file.php/?utm_source=blablabla
3. mydomain.com/* -> nothing happens, no redirect, it keeps my current rewrite rule that goes to /myhotsite.php?ID=$1

In case 2, I need to keep the query strings, that will go to Google Analytics (as long as I'm concerned, I need to use QSA, but not sure how to)

So, how do you think that we can solve this in the easiest way?

And which rule will have priority: the one that I already have or the one that you will help me to create?

Answer (score 0):

Both 1 and 2 are handled with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /folder/file.php [L]
```

Query strings are automatically appended. You'd need to place this before your other rule.

Comment: Jon Lin, how about a [R] and/or [QSA]. Is not necessary?

Comment: And it doesn't require any Rewritecond? Is that simple?

Comment: @user1406330 not unless there are other special requirements, like multiple hosts. `QSA` isn't needed because the query string is automatically appended unless your target includes a `?`. `R` is for redirecting, if you want to redirect instead of internally rewriting, add the R.

Comment: I have made a test with the RewriteRule you gave me, but 2 things occured: 1) on the page, the links where supposed to be domain.com/pub/link but they are just domain.com/link. In other words, all my links lose the dir reference, so they are point to a incorrect path 2) My flash banner also has lost the reference. It works with a XML file that is pointing to file.xml (and this file is at pub dir). Now, the banner only shows the images if the file.xml is at root dir (instead of pub). I tried to add a [R=301] but the error persists. Any idead on this? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: No idea why that's happening, something else must be causing that. The *only* thing that this rule does is take the request for `/` and serve the page `/folder/file.php`. If it is anything other than the root (`/`) this rule won't get applied.